# ASP .Net MVC get decorated roles for unathorized request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC we decorate actions using [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.100).aspx#using_authorizeattribute). When a given user is not authorized for a particular action it calls [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee427992(v=vs.100).aspx) method. I have overridden this method in my custom class called `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`. With in the scope of my overridden `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method how do I get all the roles that current user is not part of which made him/her unauthorized? For example if I decorate my action as `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "AreaUser")]` and I come to my `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` I would like to know that the user is not part of "AreaUser" so that I can display that on a redirected permission denied page.

Comment: What am I missing?  You know they're not a member of AreaUser, because your attribute hard codes "AreaUser" as the roles that are allowed, thus if you get an Unauthorized, you know for a fact they're not a member of AreaUser.

Comment: Well, I may decorate several actions with one or more different roles with the same CustomAuthorize. I want to access that list of roles in HandleUnauthorizedRequest.

Comment: And what's wrong with the Roles property?

Comment: nothing wrong, just found that and David posted as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` has a property called `Roles` that you should be able to check to get the information you want.  As mentioned by @EricFunkenbusch you can assume that the user is not in any of those roles.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460323(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I just found that when I explored more.